# Wrappable one-line text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am writing an browser-based text editor for one of my projects. Each text has a title, which the user can edit. The user should not be able to format that title or add any html to it, it should just be a plain string.

A `<input type="text">` element would be ideal, but since titles can be very long I need line wrapping, which is something that the input tag cannot do, as far as I know.

I could use a `<textarea>`, but that would allow the user to add line breaks manually, which I don't want.

I could use `<p contenteditable="true">`, but that can add unwanted markup and the user would be able to insert manual line breaks and other markup.

I could write a whole bunch of JavaScript to validate and restrict a `<textarea>` or `contenteditable` tag, but that seems to be very error-prone and could introduce cross-browser inconsistencies. Or am I making this way too complex and there is an easy way to prevent misuse?

I'm sure people have solved this problem before. What am I missing here? Do I really need a massively complex JavaScript solution to have a wrappable one-line text input?

Incidentally, I'm using [tiptap](https://tiptap.scrumpy.io) as my editor component. I know that it can do [title inputs](https://tiptap.scrumpy.io/title) but so far I haven't figured out how to extract that title. I want it to be stored separate from the text, not as part of the text. If anybody has inputs regarding using tiptap to solve my problem, that would also qualify as an answer - although I think it's a bit overkill to use a full-fledged richtext editor for a simple, unformatted one-liner. I would prefer more lightweight solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two simple solutions :

**Disable Enter key on client side**

```js
document.querySelector('#textInput').addEventListener('keydown',
    function(event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        // If ENTER key
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault(); // do nothing
        }
    }
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <textarea id="textInput" rows=3></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

**Remove line breaks on server side**

```
let text = inputText.replace(/\n/, '');
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vjrv0c/1)

Or replace them with a space then replace double spaces with one

```
let text = inputText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vjrv0c/2)

Using **both solutions** is better than only one.

Comment: My application is frontend-heavy, so I clean up as much as possible there already. I intercept the paste event and sanitize the text there. The fact that textarea doesn't take formatted text is a plus compared to `contenteditable`, so I only have to worry about line breaks, which is easy.